# What is Classful addressing?

Tags: networking

What is Classful network addressing? When and where is it used? Do I need to know it?

Comment: How should we be able to tell you if you need to know about it?

Comment: asking if you need to know something, is intellectually lazy. but maybe smart!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know about networks, then given that you asked the question, you'd probably want to know about IPs Addresses and related topics - IP addressing schemes, subnetting..  And you'd want to know about Routing - particularly IP Routing.

Nowadays CIDR is used, as you probably know, that's Classless addressing rather than classful, hence you ask your question..

It is still worth knowing classful addressing, if you want to know CIDR, since it will help you to understand the need for CIDR. Also, sometimes people still use the terminology of classful addressing.  Furthermore, learning classful addressing is trivial compared to learning CIDR, and will not get in the way, and may even help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know Classful addresing, which is for routers.

But it would help for you to study [Classful network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network).

Comment: worth clarifying that answer, to say that the article you linked to is indeed about classful addressing, despite the way you worded your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent article that is probably really helpful for people just starting to learn basics about IP addresses, routing etc like yourself. It is just the right amount of info without getting to complex to early. Take a look at it here and leave feedback if poss. He is a friend of mine and hasn't had the site going long [IP Addresses, subnets and routing](http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/03/04/the-basics-of-ip-addressing-subnet-masks-and-routing/)